# Where should I write my Spring MVC configuration class in a n-tiers architecture in a Maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to practice what I have learned with `Spring` and `Spring-MVC` in a `n-tiers` web application. But I find difficulties regarding doing the right configuration.

So I am using `Maven`. I created 3 projects so far. The first one is responsible for a generic `Hibernate` DAO implementations. The second is my business logic layer, where I have my class DAOs and my services. The third one is where my controllers are. I want to use the `Spring` dependency injection to manage my services and DAOs instances. But wherever I put my configuration class I get an error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

First project:

[image: First project structure]

Second Project:

[image: Second project structure]

Third Project:

[image: Third project structure]

You may wonder why `AppConfig` is in both projects, that's just for debugging purposes. I don't know where exactly I should put it.

My `AppConfig` class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.controllers", "com.services", "com.dao" })
public class AppConfig {

}
```

My `SpringMvcDispatcherInitializer` class:

```
public class SpringMvcDispatcherInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

The error I receive when I run the `pfa-web` project on `Maven` server:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'touristService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'touristDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'touristDaoImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your first and second project into your dependencies at third project. Here is sample of my project build with 2 modules.
[image]
This is how i configure my project :
 1. Put core-module in my app-module dependency
[image]
 2. Call it from Main
[image]

Hopefully it can help.

Comment: I did the right configuration regarding the dependencies. It's not the problem I am facing. Thanks for your answer.